# How to create a image backup of the Ubuntu server

Tags: server, backup

I'm looking for a method to do system image backup on Ubuntu Server, such as  AIX mksysb command, which allow us to boot the system from tape or DVD in order to restore the operating system and its configurations.
Somebody can help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how about `remastersys`?

Comment: First of all, thank you for reply. I don't know remastersys, but it might be a good start point.